# Programs keep using the default “Documents” folder even when I moved it to a different drive

Tags: windows-10

So, I moved every default folder from my C drive to my secondary HHD to keep my SSD clean. (With the properties method.) However, programs that use the documents' folder for keeping data, like games and some other software. Keep saving their data on the Original location. Anyway to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programs can use an API to find what Windows says is the current Documents folder, and ideally should do this each time they access the folder, but nothing in Windows forces a program to use it.

So it's possible that programs will stay using the folder they were first configured to use (and the default was the current Documents folder).

You may have to reconfigure or even reinstall the programs in question to get them to recognize the change.  Some badly coded programs may still use the C: drive no matter what you do.

Comment: Yeah, because I am quite sure the first thing I did was changing the paths. So I guess they just hardcoded?

Comment: Most likely.  Especially if they are older programs.

Comment: Try the following two commands in the Explorer Address bar to verify that both point to your redirected folder: 
 `shell:personal` and `shell:local documents`.